# mostrar usuario de una tabla symfony

Tags: symfony

Necesito ver un perfil de usuario de la tabla de usuarios que genero, pero cuando hago click en uno, me saca el usuario con el que estoy logeado:
Esta es mi funcion del controlador para ver el perfil de usuario,  en la ruta coge la id del usuario al que hago click, pero luego me imprime los datos del usuario logeado.

```
        public function usuarios_ver(UserInterface $user){
            
        if(!$user || $user->getRole() !== 'ROLE_ADMIN'){
            return $this->redirectToRoute('tasks');
        }

        return $this->render('user/ver.html.twig',[
            'user' =>$user
               
                
        ]);
```

este es mi repositorio con todo el código restante:
https://github.com/luishgc93-cc/sym-pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al pasarle por parametro el User interface le estas diciendo que coja el user interface que symfony conoce, es decir con el que estás logueado.

Supongo que tendrás una tabla de usuarios o users y tendrás la entity creada también para esa tabla.

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
/** @var ManagerRegistry $manager **/
// Puedes dejar lo que pone 'tu_manager' sin nada si no tienes varios managers configurados
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('tu_manager');
/** @var UsersRepository $users **/
$users = $manager->getRepository(Users::class);
/** @var Users $user **/
$user = $users->findOneBy(['id' => $idUsuario]);

return $this->render(
    'user/ver.html.twig',
    [
        'user' =>$user,
    ]
);
```

Es decir, coger un Objeto de tipo usuario según la ID del que estás buscando. O en su defecto puedes hacer una consulta directa a la base de datos sacando la conexión del manager.